# Show a Series Converges Uniformly to a Doubly Periodic Meromophic Function

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a problem from Gamelin's textbook that I am trying to solve:

Let $w_1$ and $w_2$ be two complex numbers that do not lie on the same line through $0$. Ket $k \geq 3$. Show that the series:
$$
\sum_{m,n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-(mw_1+nw_2))^k}
$$
converges uniformly on any bounded subset of the complex plane to a doubly periodic meromorphic function $f(z)$, whose periods are generated by $w_1$ and $w_2$.

I am having an issue seeing the image of the term inside the summation, which I think is essential for me to understand this question. But I could be totally wrong, too.

Comment: What exactly do you have problems with? To show that the series converges to a meromorphic function $f$, or to show that $f$ has periods $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$?

Comment: I’d say both. Right now I am being stuck with the first one but not sure if I could do the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U = \{ sw_1+tw_2, s,t\in (-3/4,3/4)\}$. Then
$$z^k f(z)=\sum_{m,n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(z-(mw_1+nw_2))^k}$$
converges uniformly on $U$ and it is holomorphic since its derivative is $$(z^k f(z))'=\sum_{m,n} \frac{(z-(mw_1+nw_2)) k z^{k-1}-k z^k}{(z-(mw_1+nw_2))^{k+1}}$$

So $z^k f(z)$ is analytic on $U$.

Thus $f$ is meromorphic on $U$. Since it is obvious that $f(z)=f(z+w_1)=f(z+w_2)$ we get that $f$ is meromorphic on $$\bigcup_{n,m}( U+mw_1+nw_2)=\Bbb{C}$$
Do you see where are its poles ?